# Handling an invalid security certificate using MATLAB's urlread command

Tags: java, matlab, https, ssl-certificate, urlread

I'm accessing an internal database using MATLAB's [`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html) command, everything was working fine until the service was moved to a secure server (i.e. with an HTTPS address rather than an HTTP address). Now `urlread` no longer successfully retrieves results. It gives an error:

> Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy settings improperly configured.

I believe the problem is that the service is using an invalid digital certificate since if I try to access the resource directly in a web browser I get "untrusted connection" warning which I am able to pass through by adding the site to an Exception list. `urlread` doesn't have an obvious way of handling this problem.

Under the hood `urlread` is using Java to access web resources, and the error is thrown at this line:

```
inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream;
```

where `urlConnection` is a Java object: `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl`.

Anyone suggest a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? There may not be a workaround: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1B8G6/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1B8G6

Comment: I'm on 2009a. I'd seen the solution you linked to, I don't think this is the problem. I think the urlread function supports https - but can't handle invalid security certificates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following Java class. Borrowing from this code: [Disabling Certificate Validation in an HTTPS Connection](https://web.archive.org/web/20061217061841/http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html)

#### C:\MATLAB\MyJavaClasses\com\stackoverflow\Downloader.java

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;

public class Downloader {
    public static String getData(String address) throws Exception {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

        // Create a host name verifier that always passes
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);

        // open connection
        URL page = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        // read text
        String line;
        StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
        while ( (line = buff.readLine()) != null ) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            text.append(line + "\n");
        }
        buff.close();

        return text.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        String str = getData("https://expired.badssl.com/");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

#### MATLAB

First we compile the Java class (we must use a JDK version compatible with MATLAB):

```
>> version -java
>> system('javac C:\MATLAB\MyJavaClasses\com\stackoverflow\Downloader.java');
```

Next we instantiate and use it MATLAB as:

```
javaaddpath('C:\MATLAB\MyJavaClasses')
dl = com.stackoverflow.Downloader;
str = char(dl.getData('https://expired.badssl.com/'));
web(['text://' str], '-new')
```

Here are a few URLs with bad SSL certificates to test:

```
urls = {
    'https://expired.badssl.com/'       % expired
    'https://wrong.host.badssl.com/'    % wrong host
    'https://self-signed.badssl.com/'   % self-signed
    'https://revoked.grc.com/'          % revoked
};
```

---

**UPDATE:** I should mention that starting with R2014b, MATLAB has a new function [`webread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) that supersedes [`urlread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html).

Comment: Thanks Amro - that appears to be working for a test case with an invalid certificate! My Java competence is a bit minimal and I ended up taking the package statement out to get it to work, possibly if I put stuff into the right directory structure I wouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @amadeus: thanks for fixing the link. FWIW, here's the old page as captured by the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20121022013056/http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html)

Comment: An alternate solution is to import the website certificate in question as trusted into MATLAB's JRE keystore. See here for instructions: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92506-can-i-force-urlread-and-other-matlab-functions-which-access-internet-websites-to-open-secure-websi

Comment: How would I go about implementing this code if I am running R2015a on OS X? This appears to be a solution to an exact problem I'm having, but I have almost no Java experience and am not sure how to put this solution to use. Thanks for the help

Comment: @dwm8: you would need the [Java JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) (must be version 1.7.x) to compile the above Java class `javac Downloader.java`, add the directory to the MATLAB Java classpath as above (mind the package layout), and use it the class from inside MATLAB. So let's say you have `~/dev/com/stackoverflow/Downloader.java` compiling it produces `~/dev/com/stackoverflow/Downloader.class`. Then in MATLAB you add `javaaddpath('~/dev')` and use it as `d = com.stackoverflow.Downloader()`

Comment: @dwm8 I updated the answer with more instructions. Also worth checking out the new `webread` function in MATLAB

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the solution. It worked, however, sometimes, I had received the following exception "java.io.IOException: The issuer can not be found in the trusted CA list." and I was not able to get rid of this error.

Therefore, I tried an alternative solution that works well. You can use the following Java code in Matlab function:

```
 function str = ReadUrl(url)
     is = java.net.URL([], url, sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler).openConnection().getInputStream(); 
     br = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(is));
     str = char(br.readLine());
 end
```

Best,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the "canonical" way to solve this issue is to import the certificate into MATLAB's keystore (i.e., *not* your JVM's keystore).

This is documented here: [Mathworks on using untrusted SSL certificates](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92506).