# Saving html page from MATLAB web browser

Tags: matlab, save

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610550/getting-data-into-matlab-from-https) I get a message on the retrieved page that "**Your browser does not support JavaScript so some functionality may be missing!**"

If I open this page with `web(url)` in MATLAB web browser and accept certificate (once per session), the page opens properly.

How can I save the page source from the browser with a script? Or from system browser? Or may be there is a way to get that page even without browser?

```
url='https://cgwb.nci.nih.gov/cgi-bin/hgTracks?position=chr7:55054218-55242525';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could tell the page source gets downloaded just fine, just make sure to let Javascript run when you open the saved page locally.

```
[...]
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/hgTracks.js'></script>
<noscript><b>Your browser does not support JavaScript so some functionality may be missing!</b></noscript>
[...]
```

Note that the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638275/handling-an-invalid-security-certificate-using-matlabs-urlread-command/1640099#1640099) you are using only downloads the web page without any of the attached stuff (images, .css, .js, etc..).

What you can do is call `wget` to get the page with all of its files:

```
url = 'https://cgwb.nci.nih.gov/cgi-bin/hgTracks?position=chr7:55054218-55242525';
command = ['wget --no-check-certificate --page-requisites ' url];
system( command );
```

If you are on a Windows machine, you can always get wget from the GnuWin32 project or from one of the [many other implementations](http://www.google.com/search?q=wget+windows).

Comment: The problem is I need to select some additional tracks. Then those settings are saved. Browser's cache or cookies, or session (some session id is passed), not sure. I can set it up with a browser. But how I can do it with page after wget?

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question.. Are you trying to pass POST-data and use cookies/session-cookies? If thats the case check the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

Will saving cookies be sufficient for solving your problem? wget can do that with --keep-session-cookies and --save-cookies *filename*; then you use --load-cookies *filename* to get your cookies back on subsequent requests. Something like the following (note I have not tested this from Matlab, so quoting, etc, might not be exactly right, but I do use a similar shell construction in other contexts):

```
command_init = ['wget --no-check-certificate \
                      --page-requisites \
                      --keep-session-cookies \
                      --save-cookies cookie_file.txt \
                      --post-data \'user=X&pass=Y&whatever=TRUE\'' \
                      init_url];
command_get  = ['wget --no-check-certificate \
                      --page-requisites \
                      --load-cookies cookie_file.txt' \
                      url];
```

If you don't have any post-data, but rather subsequent gets will update cookies, you can simply use keep and save on successive get requests.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer this old question. Hardly remember now by I did solved the problem. Anyway, good point.