# RESTful webservices in Matlab with authentication

Tags: web-services, matlab, restful-authentication

I have been able to get the following Matlab plugin to work with my JSON return string: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23393 (I am just copy and pasting the JSON into a file from my web browser)

However the RESTful webservice that I am hitting requires a login.  I have been able to do this in java using `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;` but can't seem to find a clean way of doing this in Matlab ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab allows the [integration of and use of Java](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4863.html) Classes and Methods.  So if you already have the code working in Java, I'd just use that code in matlab.

**Edit**: If you're dead set on using matlab then you should probably check out [urlread2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/). Although I have no clue if you can use it to save and use session cookies.

Comment: this is true and for the timing of my project I may have to go this way.  Just putting the question out there to see if I can do all in matlab

Comment: @onzyone I think the biggest problem you're going to run into is how you handle the cookies. I haven't found anything about how to store and use cookies in matlab.

Comment: @onzyone you might use something `wget` to handle the cookies for you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8649280/694184