# reading an html with matlab

Tags: java, matlab, urlread

I would like to read some html using matlab.
I've already tried urlread but got the url read error

[Getting data into MATLAB from HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610550/getting-data-into-matlab-from-https):

so i tried using java with this:

[Handling an invalid security certificate using MATLAB's urlread command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638275/handling-an-invalid-security-certificate-using-matlabs-urlread-command).

unfortunately i don't know how to use java with matlab.
so i tried this code and it seems to work

```
  url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053664/use-java-in-matlab';
  is = java.net.URL([], url ).openConnection().getInputStream(); 
  br = java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(is));
  str = char(br.readLine());
```

however i would like to get the whole html page. so i can use regexp.
My kingdom for some help

Comment: regex? on html? down that path [lies madness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in matlab that does that... The name is urlread!

See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/973

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for but this also helps. In fact the latest version of matlab solves the problem. Many thanks